# Batch Norm - Extract Running Mean & Running Variance in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, batch-normalization

I am trying to look at the running mean and running variance of a trained tensorflow model that is exported via GCMLE (`saved_model.pb`, `assets/*` & `variables/*`). Where are these values kept in the graph? I can access gamma/beta values from `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` but I have not been able to find the running mean and running variance in any of the `tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES`. Are the running mean and running variance stored somewhere else?

I know that at test time (ie. `Modes.EVAL`), the running mean and running variance are used to normalize the incoming data, then the normalized data is scaled and shifted using gamma and beta. I am trying to look at all of the variables that I need at inference time, but I cannot find the running mean and running variance. Are these only used at test time and not at inference time (`Modes.PREDICT`)? If so, that would explain why I can't find them in the exported model, but I am expecting them to be there.

Based on [tf.GraphKeys](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys) I have tried other things like `tf.GraphKeys.MOVING_AVERAGE_VARIABLES` but they are also empty. I also saw this line in the batch_normalization documentation "Note: when training, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be updated. By default the update ops are placed in `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`, so they need to be added as a dependency to the train_op." so I then tried looking at `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` from my saved model and they contain an assign op `batch_normalization/AssignMovingAvg:0` but still not clear where I would get the value from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the moving mean and moving variance are stored within `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` and it looks like the reason nothing showed up in `MODEL_VARIABLES` is because you need to use `tf.contrib.framework.local_variable`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to #reese0106's answer, 
**if you'd like to take out the moving_mean, moving_variance for BatchNorm,**
 you can index them with names as follows.

```
vars = tf.global_variables() # shows every variable being used.
vars_moving_mean_variance = []
for var in vars:
    if ("moving_mean" in var.name) or ("moving_variance" in var.name):
        vars_moving_mean_variance.append(var)

print(vars_moving_mean_variance)
```

---

p.s. Thanks for the question and the answer. I solved my own problem too.